# How to create a multi-year scatter graph in Excel?

Tags: excel, graph

Have a table in Excel that looks like the below:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZInK.png)
Date (Daily), Year, Month, Demand, % Gas
1/1/2018      2018   Jan    47,000   .36
1/2/2018      2018   Jan    31,000   .75
.......       ..... ...      ....
12/31/2022    2022   Dec    56,000   .63

How do I make a scatter graph with x-axis Month Jan - Dec. and y-axis % gas.  The data will be daily and each year's data will have a different color 2018-2022.  Should show a trend year over year.

The second scatter graph would have demand as the x-axis and %gas as the y-axis with the same year over year data with daily data points.

Haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Do you really want a scatter graph or do you actually want a line graph?  Scatter graphs are normally used to explore the relationship between two variables: for example demand for gas and temperature. Line graphs are more typically used to examine seasonal patterns. Monthly demand is OK, but daily demand will have two cyclical components: time of year and day of week. You might want to to think a bit further about how these two components can be considered using graphical methods.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  I was able to create separate series after watching a youtube video and then added them to the first series one at a time to show the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Created each year's data as separate tables.  Created a scatter graph out of the first year's data and then copy pasted (special) the other tables into the first graph with the same x-axis Jan 1 - Dec 31 without a specific year.  Formatted the axis sizing, labels and then added linear trendlines to finish out the graph.